# How to use ESP8266-01 module GPIO pins for temperature sensing with NodeMCU

Tags: lua, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

How can i use ESP8266-01 module GPIO pins for temperature sensing in a ESP8266 standalone environment using NodeMCU ROM. If possible than what will be the lua code for it ?

Will the programming/flashing of ESP8266 will be same irrespective of the module version i'm using be it ESP8266-01 or ESP8266-07.

Comment: Which temperature sensor do you intend to use?

Answer (score 0):

How to use the GPIO pins depends on which temperature sensor you will use. Or more specifically which protocol they use (assuming it's a digital and not a analog sensor, a analog sensor can't really (well easily) be used with a GPIO pin.)
But basically you'll just wire the data pin of the sensor to the GPIO pin, using whatever electric circuit is relevant for the type of sensor.

You will preferably use the latest NodeMCU firmware (1.5.1), which you will need to build using their online build service (it's easy :) ). While doing this you need to choose the modules you'll want available, which must include support for the sensor you'll be using.

Flashing will be the same for any ESP module, except for having to specify a different flash size/mode, and you might need to add a reset and flash button for 'bare' modules.

Programming (=LUA) will be identical for any module, once you've flashed the NodeMCU firmware. Except ofcourse that you might specify a different GPIO pin.

As an example of LUA code, for a ds18b20 sensor, you could look at:

- https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/lua_examples/onewire-ds18b20.lua
- https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/lua_examples/yet-another-ds18b20.lua

But this will be different for each type of sensor.

Comment: Thanks Cranphin, ds18b20  digital sensor can be one solution but I was intending to use lm35/analog temperature sensor which i guess can be integrated with only ADC/TOUT pin of ESP8255-12e not with other modules.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with analog sensors is indeed that the ESP8266 has very limited analog inputs, just the ADC pin, and it can only measure 0.0-1.0V. So that would be an option, you can still use NodeMCU firmware and lua, which allows you to read the  ADC pin, and you need a circuit to convert your sensors output to a 0-1V range. It might not be very accurate/stable :)

Comment: Actually, for 0 - 100 degrees celcius, it seems the lm35 would output in the 0-1V range, so you could just hook the output directly to ADC :)

Comment: Ah, only catch is you can't use ESP8266-01, it doesn't expose the ADC pin. unless you do some super tricky soldering :)